# Why does my script only save the last H2 tag in my xml file into the database?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, domdocument, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to store all the H2 tags into my database.
I'm using **Laravel** **5.4** and **DomDocument**.

How i retrieve the h2 tags:

```
$htag2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

**My h2 tags:**

```
<h2> htag2-1 </h2>
<h2> htag2-2 </h2>
<h2> htag2-3 </h2>
<h2> htag2-4 </h2>
```

This is the output in the database: `htag2-4`. As you can see it skips the other 3 h2tags in my xml file.

I'm trying to save this using for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $htag2->length; $i++) {
 $ts->h2_tag = $htag2->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
```

Declaration for $ts: `$ts = new Scan;`

Comment: Is $ts->h2_tag an array?

Comment: Hi Alex, no. h2_tag is a string: $table->string('h2_tag');

I've tried to turn it into an array but i don't understand how to do that..

Comment: Do you know how to fill this? $table->$arrayName = array('' => , );

Comment: Your model only has one h2_tag but you are setting it 4 times, thats why you get `htag2-4`, you have overwritten it 4 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code fist you need to do is to collect all elements in some array, for example:

```
$h2Array = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $htag2->length; $i++) {
    $h2Array[] = $htag2->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
```

And then do operation with collected items. Or you can just insert them one by one in **for** statement.

Comment: Hey Alex, 

I'm getting this error: Array to string conversion. What can i do?

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 647

Comment: I mean, where did you use **$h2Array** to insert it to database?

Comment: In the for loop

Comment: $ts->h2_tag = $h2Array;

Comment: Aha, so you can do `$ts->h2_tag = implode($h2Array, ',');`

Comment: You are welcome :) But anyway I can't see full part of code. Maybe there is can be more convenient implementation

Comment: Now you're here. How can i implement enters instead of comma's? I've tried \n but that doesn't work

Comment: Try **<br>** tag if you're outputting it in html